# Import fails with a strange error

Tags: python, django, python-import

I get:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /blog/post/test
>   Caught NameError while rendering:
>   global name 'forms' is not defined

for this code:
**forms.py**

```
from dojango.forms import widgets
from django.contrib.comments.forms import CommentForm
from Website.Comments.models import PageComment

class PageCommentForm(CommentForm):
    title = widgets.TextInput()
    rating = widgets.RatingInput()

    def get_comment_model(self):
        return PageComment

    def get_comment_create_data(self):
        # Use the data of the superclass, and add in the title field
        data = super(PageComment, self).get_comment_create_data()
        data['title'] = self.cleaned_data['title']
        return data
```

**models.py**

```
from Website.CMS.models import Author, Rating
from django.db.models import CharField, ForeignKey
from django.contrib.comments.models import Comment

class PageComment(Comment):
    title = CharField(max_length=300)
    parent = ForeignKey(Author, related_name='parent_id', null=True)
    author = ForeignKey(Author, related_name='author_id')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class CommentRating(Rating):
    comment = ForeignKey(PageComment)
```

**__init__.py**

```
from Website.Comments import *

def get_model():
    return models.PageComment

def get_form():
    return forms.PageCommentForm #error here
```

importing form directly inside **init**.py results in:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no
>   attribute 'Comments'

Here's the stack trace, the error appears to be coming from dojango but that doesn't really make sense:

> File
>   "I:\wamp\www\Website\Comments__init__.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       from Website.Comments import models, forms   File
>   "I:\wamp\www\Website\Comments\forms.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       from dojango import forms   File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\dojango\forms__init__.py",
>   line 2, in 
>       from widgets import *   File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\dojango\forms\widgets.py",
>   line 11, in 
>       from dojango.util.config import Config   File
>   "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\dojango\util\config.py",
>   line 3, in 
>       from dojango.util import media   File
>   "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\dojango\util\media.py",
>   line 49, in 
>       for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File
>   "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\dojango\util\media.py",
>   line 49, in 
>       for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File
>   "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\dojango\util\media.py",
>   line 38, in find_ pp_dojo_dir_and_url
>       media_dir = find_app_dojo_dir(app_name)   File
>   "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\dojango\util\media.py",
>   line 27, in find_ pp_dojo_dir
>       base = find_app_dir(app_name)   File
>   "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\dojango\util\media.py",
>   line 20, in find_ pp_dir
>       mod = getattr(**import**(m, {}, {}, [a]), a)

The Comments app is in the installed apps.
What should I do?

EDIT:
If I try to include forms directly with `import forms` I get this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "I:\wamp\www\Website\manage.py", line 11, in 
>      execute_manager(settings)
>    File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line
>   438, in execute_manager
>      utility.execute()
>    File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line
>   379, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>     File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 191,
>    in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **options.**dict**)
>     File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 209,
>    in execute
>       translation.activate('en-us')
>     File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation__init__.py", lin
>   e 66, in activate
>       return real_activate(language)
>     File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 55, in _
>   curried
>       return _curried_func(*(args+moreargs), **dict(kwargs, **morekwargs))
>     File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation__init__.py", lin
>   e 36, in delayed_loader
>       return getattr(trans, real_name)(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", l
>   ine 193, in activate
>       _active[currentThread()] = translation(language)
>     File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", l
>   ine 176, in translation
>       default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
>     File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", l
>   ine 159, in _fetch
>       app = import_module(appname)
>     File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in im
>   port_module
>       **import**(name)
>     File "I:\wamp\www\Website\Comments__init__.py", line 2, in 
>       import forms
>     File "I:\wamp\www\Website\Comments\forms.py", line 3, in 
>       from dojango.forms import fields, widgets
>     File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\dojango\forms__init__.py", line 2, in 
>       from widgets import *
>     File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\dojango\forms\widgets.py", line 11, in 
>       from dojango.util.config import Config
>     File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\dojango\util\config.py", line 3, in 
>       from dojango.util import media
>     File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\dojango\util\media.py", line 49, in 
>       for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>     File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\dojango\util\media.py", line 49, in 
>       for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>     File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\dojango\util\media.py", line 38, in find_a
>   pp_dojo_dir_and_url
>       media_dir = find_app_dojo_dir(app_name)
>     File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\dojango\util\media.py", line 27, in find_a
>   pp_dojo_dir
>       base = find_app_dir(app_name)
>     File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\dojango\util\media.py", line 20, in find_a
>   pp_dir
>       mod = getattr(**import**(m, {}, {}, [a]), a)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Comments'

Removing any reference for dojango solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in dojango.
I will report it.

Answer (score 0):

put the following in __init__.py:

```
import forms
```

Comment: because it's inside __init__.py I can't specify the full module path? But why removing `from dojango.forms import widgets` and all dojango references helps? Is it because dojango also has a forms app? I'm confused. Can you tell me why this error happens?

Comment: yes, I believe there is a django.forms. You may want to try:
    from my_project import forms

where my_project is the name of the root directory you are in, I think *Website* in your case.

Comment: When I do from Website.Comments import forms that I get an error too, see question for details

Comment: I am positive that the problem is with dojango.forms. Any idea why?